# SDL video driver

Tags: c, sdl

I'm currently working on a code that uses SDL to display video and as i'm working through ssh, i'm looking for something like a text driver (just need to avoid seing the video because it's so slow).

So what I need is a simple way to avoid screen init and all that stuff that keep my framerate below 15fps :)

Does anyone know something that might help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you want. But try:

```
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy
```

Comment: can you give me more info on this "dummy" driver? it seems to be nice too!

Comment: @claferri [Look here](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars). You will be able to use all the functions, but the driver doesn't create any windows and doesn't output anything. You won't be able to use OpenGL and will not get any input events (you need to read your input from console). If you want to see anything you can take screenshot with `SDL_SaveBMP(screen, "image.bmp")`.

Answer (score 3):

How about using aalib as video driver? This will output all graphics as ascii art. From the SDL FAQ:

> Building SDL: make distclean; ./configure --enable-video-aalib ; make install Running your app: set the environment variable SDL_VIDEODRIVER to "aalib".

Cheers

Comment: I'm going to try that right away, if that work, it's exactly what i'm looking for I guess!

Comment: Ok it seems to be what i'm looking for but the thing is : it doesnt print anything, i can just see the ascii shade of my mouse when moving it. I tested aalib with mplayer, it works fine. any clue?

Comment: No, not really. The only thing I can think of right know may be that aalib can not handle hardware surfaces. Just try software surface and if it doesn't work, try the dummy driver as suggested by banthar

Comment: Yeah the dummy driver seems to be the perfect thing for me, thanks anyway!